# Is it possible to create a javascript User-defined function in sqlite

Tags: javascript, sqlite

BACKGROUND:

- Firefox 3 includes
  [SQLite](http://sqlite.org) version
  3.5.9. Firefox also allows extensions, which are written in javascript and
  can call the embedded SQLite engine.
- As expected, executing the following
  SQL statement 'SELECT "TEXT" REGEXP
  "T*";' gives an error, since there is
  no REGEXP function natively included in SQLite.
- javascript includes a built in regexp function.
- SQLite allows loadable extensions via SELECT load_extension('filename');

QUESTION:
**Is it possible to a load an extension in SQLite which is written in javascript that can do REGEXP?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to call javascript functions

```
//(thanks to Mirnal Kant, SQLManager)
//Version 2 -- Prevent Firefox crashing 
//          -- Suspect a problem with continual creation of Regex objects

var g_RegExpString = null;
var g_RegExp = null;

//functions to be created for the db
var smDbFunctions = { 
  // (0) = Regex Expression
  // (1) = Column value to test
    regexp: {
        onFunctionCall: function(val) {
            if (g_RegExp == null || val.getString(0) != g_RegExpString) 
            {
                g_RegExpString = val.getString(0);
                g_RegExp = new RegExp(g_RegExpString);
            }
            if (val.getString(1).match(g_RegExp)) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

after instantiating a SQLite instance:

```
Database.createFunction("REGEXP", 2, smDbFunctions.regexp);
```

Answer (score 3):

What Noah is talking about has been included into [SQLite Manager](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/) add-on for Firefox.

When you start this add-on, you can click the icon labeled *f(x)* to open the User-defined functions tab. From there, select a directory in which you have an SQLite database named smFunctions.sqlite, with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "functions"          ( "name"        TEXT    PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL
                                  , "body"        TEXT                 NOT NULL
                                  , "argLength"   INTEGER
                                  , "aggregate"   INTEGER              NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
                                  , "enabled"     INTEGER              NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
                                  , "extraInfo"   TEXT
                                  );

CREATE TABLE "aggregateFunctions" ( "name"        TEXT    PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL
                                  , "argLength"   INTEGER
                                  , "onStepBody"  TEXT
                                  , "onFinalBody" TEXT
                                  , "enabled"     INTEGER              NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
                                  , "extraInfo"   TEXT
                                  );
```

Inside that table you can define custom functions. Parameters will be passed as an array named `aValues`. For example:

```
INSERT INTO "functions" ("name", "body", "argLength", "aggregate", "enabled", "extraInfo")
VALUES('regexp_replace'
      ,'// exemple : SELECT regexp_replace(''FOOBAR'',''o+'',''a'',''gi'')
        var input      = new String(aValues.getString(0));
        var regex      = new String(aValues.getString(1));
        var substitute = new String(aValues.getString(2));
        var flags      = new String(aValues.getString(3));

        return input.replace(new RegExp(regex,flags), substitute);
       '
      ,4
      ,0
      ,1
      ,''
      );
```

- if `argLength` == -1, then there is no limit on the number of arguments. You can get the count with `aValues.numEntries`.
- You can use `aValues.getTypeOfIndex(i)` to know the type of the argument: 0 => NULL, 1 => Integer (`aValues.getInt64(i)`), 2 => Real (`aValues.getDouble(i)`), 3 => String, see example.

For aggregate functions you can use `this._store` as an initially empty array to push the elements during the onStepBody phase, and read from it in `onStepFinal` to compute the final result.

Below is a bash script that will create `smFunctions.sqlite` with some custom functions (this is a `.dump` of my own smFunctions.sqlite):

```
sqlite smFunctions.sqlite << EOF
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE "functions" ("name" TEXT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL, "body" TEXT NOT NULL, "argLength" INTEGER, "aggregate" INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0, "enabled" INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 1, "extraInfo" TEXT);
INSERT INTO "functions" VALUES('accumulate','var sum = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < aValues.numEntries; j++) {
    sum += aValues.getInt32(j);
}
return sum;
',-1,0,1,NULL);
INSERT INTO "functions" VALUES('concatenate','var valArr = [];
var delim = new String(aValues.getString(0));
for (var j = 1; j < aValues.numEntries; j++) {
    switch (aValues.getTypeOfIndex(j)) {
    case 0:
        //NULL
        valArr.push(null);
        break;
    case 1:
        //INTEGER
        valArr.push(aValues.getInt64(j));
        break;
    case 2:
        //REAL
        valArr.push(aValues.getDouble(j));
        break;
    case 3:
        //TEXT
    default:
        valArr.push(aValues.getString(j));
    }
}
return valArr.join(delim);',-1,0,1,NULL);
INSERT INTO "functions" VALUES('regexp_match','var regExp = new RegExp(aValues.getString(0));
var strVal = new String(aValues.getString(1));

if (strVal.match(regExp)) {
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 0;
}

',2,0,1,NULL);
INSERT INTO "functions" VALUES('regexp_replace','// exemple : regexp_replace(''toto'',''o+'',''a'',''g'')
var input      = new String(aValues.getString(0));
var regex      = new String(aValues.getString(1));
var substitute = new String(aValues.getString(2));
var flags      = new String(aValues.getString(3));

return input.replace(new RegExp(regex,flags), substitute);
',4,0,1,NULL);
INSERT INTO "functions" VALUES('instr','var char = new String(aValues.getString(0));
var str  = new String(aValues.getString(1));
return str.indexOf(char, 0) + 1;',2,0,1,NULL);
INSERT INTO "functions" VALUES('rinstr','var char = new String(aValues.getString(0));
var str  = new String(aValues.getString(1));
return str.lastIndexOf(char) + 1;
',2,0,1,NULL);
CREATE TABLE "aggregateFunctions" ("name" TEXT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL, "argLength" INTEGER, "onStepBody" TEXT, "onFinalBody" TEXT, "enabled" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, "extraInfo" TEXT);
INSERT INTO "aggregateFunctions" VALUES('stdDev',1,'this._store.push(aValues.getInt32(0));','var iLength = this._store.length;
let total = 0;
this._store.forEach(function(elt) { total += elt });
let mean = total / iLength;
let data = this._store.map(function(elt) {
  let value = elt - mean;
  return value * value;
});
total = 0;
data.forEach(function(elt) { total += elt });
this._store = [];
return Math.sqrt(total / iLength);',1,NULL);
INSERT INTO "aggregateFunctions" VALUES('longest_prefix',1,'this._store.push(aValues.getString(0));','if (this._store.length == 0) {
        return "";
}
var prefix = this._store[0];
var prefixLen = prefix.length;
for (var i = 1; i < this._store.length && prefixLen > 0; i++) {
        var word = this._store[i];
        // The next line assumes 1st char of word and prefix always match.
        // Initialize matchLen to -1 to test entire word.
        var matchLen = 0;
        var maxMatchLen = Math.min(word.length, prefixLen);
        while (++matchLen < maxMatchLen) {
                if (word.charAt(matchLen) != prefix.charAt(matchLen)) {
                        break;
                }
        }
        prefixLen = matchLen;
}
return prefix.substring(0, prefixLen);',1,NULL);
COMMIT;
EOF
```