# Can a sqlite statement load a string from the database and interpret it as a statement?

Tags: sqlite

I would like to load text from a field in a SQLite table and run it as a SQLite query. All done in a SQLite query. No external string operations, nor command line operations are possible. Pure SQLite only.

Let's say that I would create a table `command_table` with the rows:

```
COMMAND_NAME:  COMMAND:
command1        SELECT * FROM table1
command2        SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.row1 = '1'
```

The desired SQLite command would be able to load the COMMAND and interpret it.
The commands would be as complex as it gets, so using some generic comparisons like
 `WHERE table1.row1 = command_table.command1"` is not an option.

Comment: Looks like you are duplicating the view functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating stored procedure and SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335162/creating-stored-procedure-and-sqlite)

Comment: Yeah, that looks like what I needed, and therefor am not able to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is designed as an embedded database, i.e., to be used together with a 'real' programming language. Therefore, it does not have any mechanism to execute dynamic SQL statements from within SQL itself.

Comment: Thank You for clarification.