# Does SQLite support stored procedures?

Tags: sqlite, stored-procedures

I am evaluating the SQLite database for my requirement. Does SQLite support stored procedures?

If yes then what are the limitations? Does SQLite support the range?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating stored procedure and SQLite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335162/creating-stored-procedure-and-sqlite)

Answer (score 15):

No, it does not.  See [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) on the main site.

Comment: Thanks, any other database which support the store procedures? I am looking for in process database. means, where don't need any configuration just copy that file and use it.

Answer (score 10):

A key reason for having stored procs in a database is that you're executing SP code in the same process as the SQL engine. This makes sense for database engines designed to work as a network connected service but the imperative for SQLite is much less. Given that it run as a DLL in your current process it makes more sense to implement SP in the client language.

You can however extend SQLite with your own [user defined functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108870/how-to-create-custom-functions-in-sqlite) in the host language (PHP, Python, Perl, C#, [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455292/is-it-possible-to-create-a-javascript-user-defined-function-in-sqlite), [Ruby](http://viewsourcecode.org/why/hacking/aQuickGuideToSQLite.html) etc). I've [done this in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172735/create-use-user-defined-functions-in-system-data-sqlite) using [DevArt's SQLite](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/UDF.html) to implement password hashing.

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to store SQL code in the DB (such as when you want to develop cross-platform apps), you can create a specific table that will store raw SQL commands that do the thing, then in the client you obtain the SQL command. e.g.

```
var myString = db.CreateCommand("SELECT SqlColumn FROM tablewithsqlcommands WHERE Procname=theprocedureIwant").ExecuteScalar();
```

and then execute it in the second step

```
var myResult = db.CreateCommand(myString).whatever_execution_method_you_need();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use this:

[Stored Procedures for SQLite](https://github.com/aergoio/sqlite-stored-procedures)

Here is how to create a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_new_sale(@products) BEGIN 
 SET @sale_id = INSERT INTO sales (time) VALUES (datetime('now')) RETURNING id;
 FOREACH @name, @qty, @price IN @products DO 
   INSERT INTO sale_items (sale_id, name, qty, price) VALUES (@sale_id, @name, @qty, @price);
 END LOOP;
 RETURN @sale_id;
END;
```

And how to call it:

```
CALL add_new_sale(ARRAY( ARRAY('DJI Avata',2,1168.00), ARRAY('iPhone 14',1,799.90) ));
```

Note: I am the creator