# How can I put a where condition on a SqLite view statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible to rewrite the following view so that the user had the possibility to parameterize the view using `WHERE` clause (`WHERE overlap > @param`, which is commented out below)? Is it possible at all? The `where` clause should affect before the `group by` clause.

I try to select from a table `vl` and to match the rows (outer join) against rows from a statement, which counts in another table (`vlda`).

```
CREATE VIEW dr AS
SELECT
    vl.unique_object_id AS unique_object_id,
    ifnull(vlda.detectioncount, 0) AS detectioncount,
    vl.count AS labelcount,
    (1.0*ifnull(vlda.detectioncount, 0) / vl.count) AS detectionrate,
    vlda.evalround_id
    FROM viewlabelcount vl
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            count() as detectioncount,
            unique_object_id, 
            evalround_id
            FROM viewlabeldetections_best
            -- WHERE overlap > 0.5 -- is it possible to parametrize?
            GROUP BY unique_object_id
    ) AS vlda
    ON
        vl.unique_object_id = vlda.unique_object_id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite does not allow parameters in objects stored in the schema (such as views or triggers).

If you're using SQLite 3.8.3 or later, you could move that definition as a [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) into your queries.

Comment: Thx. Meanwhile I found also another option to 'emulate' the complex statements: to put the statement as text into a special table, then read the statement from the table and execute it from the application, including necessary statement parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402841/does-sqlite-support-store-procedures .