# stored updates or inserts in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, pyodbc

I saw this question here
[Run the query saved in MS Access with required parameters through Pyodbc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922378/run-the-query-saved-in-ms-access-with-required-parameters-through-pyodbc)

and wonder if this is also possible with a sqlite database and stored insert or update queries.

Comment: SQLite doesn't support things like stored procedures. The closest you get are views and triggers.

Comment: ok, let's say I have a insert or update view with parameters stored in the sqlite database. how do I create the view with parameters and how do I call it from python?

Comment: "let's say I have a insert or update view with parameters stored in the sqlite database" - Please [edit] your question to show the SQLite DDL (e.g., `CREATE VIEW` or whatever) for the thing that you would be trying to execute.

Comment: we could take a simple update statement like "update customer set zipcode 5090 where city = #parameter#

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23089335/2144390

Comment: Have you tried creating such a view?

Comment: the link sent from gord is creating a new view. this here is a stored view like the one in the link in the question.

Comment: Are you talking about a view stored in the SQLite database itself, or a saved query in an Access database that points to a SQLite database (via ODBC)?

Comment: as in the header of the question stated its about a sqlite database. But so far i understood its not possible to save a view in sqlite that updates values on a tables