# SQLITE - Storing predefined Queries outside code in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I have WPF application where there are some predefined SQL queries.I want to run these queries sequentially in one go, but I don't want to hard code these queries into C# code.Please give me some suggestions about where to  store these queries and access it to my C# code.

Comment: What database are you using? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @DanielSimpkins I am using sqlite database.

Comment: @ken2k I am using  Sqlite database and it does not support stored procedures.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402841/does-sqlite-support-store-procedures

Answer (score 1):

As @ken2k suggested, bundle all your queries in a stored procedure. You don't have to hard-code anything but provide the stored procedure name. This is a very flexible approach as you don't have to make any code changes in C# if you need to change your queries.

Comment: Does sqlite database support Stored Procedures? It doesn't.Please refer this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402841/does-sqlite-support-store-procedures

Answer (score 0):

I am using CSV file as a resource file in which I have written all my SQL queries.I am reading CSV file in my code. It helped me to keep my queries separated from my C# code.